# Use an image from public folder

Tags: html, css, scala, playframework

I'm trying to set as background an image located at `/public/images/my-image.jpg`

I've tried

```
<body background="public/images/my-image.jpg">
```

and

```
<body background="images/my-image.jpg">
```

and

```
<body background="my-image.jpg">
```

But I always get `404 (Not Found)` on the Chrome console.  Any idea why?

I also tried adding this:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("/public/images/my-image.jpg");
    }
</style>
```

But nothing appears in the background of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you've got a problems obtaining assets in playframework.
Follow the documentation for play framework for [assets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview).

To obtain assets from public directory (if you haven't change the default routes or assets controller), you need to use path with `assets/` instead of `public/`.
Or more preferable using reverse router. In play 2.5x in your case it would be:

`<body background="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/my-image.jpg")">`

using reverse routing or

`<body background="assets/images/my-image.jpg">`

with hard coded path.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a record in the `routes` file

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Then you can access the files in the `public` folder with the twirl helper:

```
<body background="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/my-image.jpg")">
```

It would be compiled to

```
<body background="/assets/images/my-image.jpg")">
```

You can put it as static text as well.

**If you want to change "assets" to "public" or whatever**, just change it in the `routes` file:

```
GET     /public/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Then your assets would be accessible by the `public` path, like:

```
<body background="/public/images/my-image.jpg")">
```

Still, the `@routes.Assets.versioned` would be the same:

```
<body background="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/my-image.jpg")">
```

This is the reason why `@routes.Assets.versioned` is preferable way.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not supported anymore in HTML5, try to use css like `body {
    background-image: url("gradient_bg.png");
}`

font: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp